# jQuery chaining

Tags: jquery, css, chaining

I don't think I'm correctly understanding jQuery chaining. I'm looping through an array and trying to add div elements to my wrapper CSS class with each div element having a class of 'click' and custom css top and left attributes, like this:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('.wrapper').addClass('click').css('top',click.y).css('left'.click.x);
```

But it fails to work as expected - it adds one div element, sets my .wrapper div's class to 'click' and then stops.

If I remove

```
.css('top',click.y).css('left'.click.x);
```

it works as expected - adding new div elements to the wrapper div.

How can i get this to work properly?
Thanks

Comment: You have a typo after 'left' of a period instead of comma

Comment: Thanks that didn't help matters

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a JSON object for `.css`.

```
.css({
   'left' : click.x,
   'top' : click.y
 });
```

Comment: That's just a regular JS object. A JSON object would be a string representation of the JS object syntax.

Comment: Mmm acutally the main problem I had (there were many) was because i wasn't adding " + 'px'" to my values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('<div>/div>').appendTo('.wrapper').addClass('click').css({
    'top': click.y,
    'left': click.x
});
```